# Is it appropriate to use a delegate here?

Tags: c#, validation, webforms, delegates

I have three potential categories of input, being a person's name, a company name or an address respectively.

Ignoring my placeholders and custom methods, here are two of them:

```
 protected void nameSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (offRadio.Checked == false && comRadio.Checked == false)
            {
                errorAlert("Please specify the search type");
            }
            else
            {

                strValidator(nameBox.Text);// This is the function I need to change.
                          //In it's current condition, it will only validate against
                          // general properties, however to do more in depth
                          // validation, the validation method needs to be dependant
                          // on the type of input


                if (nameBox.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (offRadio.Checked == true) 
                                   //This is an input of the person name category
                    {
                        logic.createQuery(fnms(nameBox.Text), 
                                                  "personName", lnms(nameBox.Text));
                    }
                    else if (comRadio.Checked == true)
                                   //And this is of the Company name category
                    {
                        logic.createQuery(nameBox.Text, "companyName");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    errorAlert("Please enter a search parameter");
                }
            }
        }
```

The objective here is to analyse the input from `nameBox.Text` and vet it against anti-injection protocols. I would like to ideally use a single method to do this, and for that method to be different based on whether the input originates from a *person's name* (`offRadio.Checked = true`), or a *company name* (`comRadio.Checked = true`). I *could* have two methods (or even one, based on a condition), but this would result in `nameSearch_Click()` becoming a relative quagmire of nested statements, which I would like to avoid.

According to some of my research, the way to do this is by using a delegate void, however I am at a loss as to how to implement this. Is my validation method to be the delegate? Or must I create a new delegate method and move the contents of my `Click` event to it?

Additionally, how do I add the logic to decide what the input category is?

Comment: Why `delegate`? Can't you call some method of validation class with some parameters (values of radio buttons or an `enum` value based on their values)? To example, `Validator.CheckUrl(textBoxUrl.Text, Validator.Mode.TrimSpaces);`

Comment: @Sinatr The idea was to keep the code as small as possible, however you may be right in that your suggestion may be my... "safest" option.

Comment: Show please *big* code and we will see.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a validate delegate would be an acceptable approach:

```
delegate void Validate(string text);

protected void nameSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Validate validate;

    if (offRadio.Checked)
        validate = PersonNameValidator;
    else if (comRadio.Checked)
        validate = CompanyNameValidator;
    else
        validate = GeneralValidator;

    validate(nameBox.Text);

    ... More code, blah blah ...
}

private void PersonNameValidator(string text)
{
    // Validate person name
}

private void CompanyNameValidator(string text)
{
    // Validate company name
}

private void GeneralValidator(string text)
{
    // Validate general properties
}
```

Normally, I would expect the `Validate` delegate to return type `bool` so it can return `false` on failure, or `true` on success. That way the validate methods are truly limited to just handling validation. The calling function would be responsible for handling failure/success.

Comment: Using delegates is adding no value here.  Rather than assigning the delegate you might as well just invoke the method; it would be functionally identical.

Comment: @Servy You may be right. However, I personally find the intention clearer, especially if the if/else chain does more than simply assign the validate variable. It puts the validation call in a single place instead of spread across several lines of if/else messiness. It also clearly shows and guarantees and that the validation methods have the same signature. You can't have one validator return a bool and another one return something else.

Comment: @Servy In this instance, I think I agree with itsme86 here, although I've learned a little more about delegates and have implemented it slightly differently.